# '...' is not a type c++ compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am writing a small game for an assignment and it requires using a map, I have successfully put the map into a 2d array, but now working further into the assignment I found I need to access the array Map[][] in another function. I have tried to get it to work but failed. The error I get with g++ is " error: 'Map' is not a type " Any help would be appreciated.

I have searched but either I am terrible at using the search engine or I couldn't find anything specific to this error.

```
const int MapSZ = 10; //In Global
int Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]; // Also Global

void GetMap(ifstream&, int); //Getting the map (Proto)

GetMap(fin, Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]); //In the main function.

void GetMap(ifstream& fin, Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]) //Inserting the map into an array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]` is defined as a global, as your comment states (i.e. it is defined in `main.cpp` but outside of the main function), there is no need to pass it as a parameter to `GetMap`. You could simply do something like

```
void GetMap(ifstream& fin); //proto

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    GetMap(fin);
}

void GetMap(ifstream& fin) {
    //some code that uses Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got it sorted. Feel so stupid now... Anyway cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
void GetMap(ifstream& fin, Map[MapSZ][MapSZ])
```

should be:

```
void GetMap(ifstream& fin, int Map[MapSZ][MapSZ]) 
                           ^^^^
```

Notice, that `Map` is the *name* of the array, but you didn't mention its *type*.

Comment: That `GetMap` would be incompatible with the earlier prototype of `GetMap`. I don't thing the overloading would be desirable here.

Comment: Thanks, I in putted the 'int' but now I get a rather odd looking compilation error    "/tmp/cc5xDEOL.o: In function `main':
P1P2.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `GetMap(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: @Joey The function call passes one int, not the entire `Map`. The correct declaration would be `void GetMap(ifstream& fin, int MapElement)` because the function doesn't know about the entire map. It's better to copy the prototype from the function definition, not from the call site. Edit: Wait, you already have a correct prototype. What is the "Inserting the map into an array
" line supposed to be?

Comment: `Map`'s type is a 2 dimensional array of integers.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That line is followed by the function that inputs the numbers into the array - see here 
for(int i = 0; i < MapSZ; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
 {
  for(int j = 0; j < MapSZ; j++) //This loops on the columns
  {
   fin >> Map[i][j] ;
  }
 }